# SQL: selecting all values that meet one criteria from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have looked up some questions relating to this topic, but can't seem to find what I need:

I have 2 tables, and I would like to append information from the main table to the other matching one criteria from both. so in one table I have zip code information, I want to append all the users from the main table which match the zip codes in the other table. so i want something like:

[image: desired result set]

any kind of pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What are those 2 tables? Please provide us with those tables information (schema)

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: @Barmar: _"we also don't answer homework questions"_ [This is not true](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/560648). You linked to a post on a different site's meta, and one from half a decade ago at that... Furthermore, I see no evidence on that page that it is saying "we don't answer homework questions" - it's much more nuanced than that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit We'll help them solve homework problems, we won't do it for them.

Comment: @Barmar: I agree that this question is probably too broad for SO, but that is (never) because it is homework.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's just a boilerplate comment, to be ignored in non-homework cases.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - thanks for being kind and accurate. I can read SQL, but am still beginner when it comes to writing it (getting there though). Thank you.

Comment: @Nancy: No problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple `JOIN` of the two tables on the `zip_code` field.  Something like:

```
SELECT z.zip_code, u.user_id
FROM MyZipCodeTable z
LEFT JOIN MyUserTable u ON z.zip_code = u.zip_code
```

This will return all zip codes and any matching users.

Comment: yes, this is exactly like the query i wrote myself, but this will only return one user id per zip code (not what i want as it is inaccurate; we have more than one user in each zip code). Thank you for answering though!

Comment: If you have multiple users with the same zip code, this will return all of them.  It will return all rows in your User table, assuming they have a matching row in your ZipCode table.  It won't look like the image you posted above, though...if that's what you mean (i.e. no converting of repeated zip code values to empty string)

Comment: Here is what I have:  select a.zip, z.user_id from [other_table]  a left join main_table z ON a.zip = z.zip . This only appends one user_id per zip code, which is inaccurate. I need all user_ids that are associated to each zip code in the list ... oh no, I'm sorry if the image is misleading: I do not mean to return empty strings. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, our queries look to be the same.  Unfortunately, it's getting difficult to visualize the exact result that you're looking for.  Can you post the exact format of the result data you want?  Also, if you can post: 1) your table definitions, 2) sample data you're using to run your query, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for all the users from the main table with zip codes in the other table. I assume you can join both tables on user_id.

To get that you want something like this:

```
SELECT main_table.*, other_table.zipcode 
FROM main_table mt
LEFT JOIN other_table ot ON mt.user_id=ot.user_id
```

Comment: you are correct in your first sentence on what I am looking for! Ok, I will try this and get back to you, and give you credit if it works! Thank you!

Comment: eh, the only flaw ( and key) i just noticed on this is that the other table does not have user_id information :/ the other table only has zip code info; i am trying to get all user id info from the main table. the only thing these tables share in common is zip info so i would have to join from that point :/ thanks!